# Unsure why output is 0. Trying to count months to pay downpayment

Tags: python, if-statement, control-flow

```
print("Please enter you starting annual salary: ")
annual_salary = float(input())
monthly_salary = annual_salary/12
 
print("Please enter your portion of salary to be saved:  ")
portion_saved = float(input())

print ("Please enter the cost of your dream home:  ")
total_cost = float(input())

current_savings = 0
r = 0.04/12
n = 0
portion_down_payment = total_cost*int(.25)

if current_savings < portion_down_payment:
  monthly_savings = monthly_salary*portion_saved  
  interest = monthly_savings*r
  current_savings = current_savings + monthly_savings + interest
  n =+ 1
else: 
  print(n)
```

The above is my code. I keep getting output = 0 but unsure why.

This the problem statement, I am a HS student attempting OCW coursework.

1. Call the cost of your dream home ​total_cost​.
2. Call the portion of the cost needed for a down payment ​portion_down_payment​. For simplicity, assume that portion_down_payment = 0.25 (25%).
3. Call the amount that you have saved thus far ​current_savings​. You start with a current savings of $0.
4. Assume that you invest your current savings wisely, with an annual return of ​r ​(in other words, at the end of each month, you receive an additional ​current_savings*r/12​ funds to put into your savings – the 12 is because ​r​ is an annual rate). Assume that your investments earn a return of r = 0.04 (4%).
5. Assume your annual salary is ​annual_salary​.
6. Assume you are going to dedicate a certain amount of your salary each month to saving for the down payment. Call that ​portion_saved​. This variable should be in decimal form (i.e. 0.1 for 10%).
7. At the end of each month, your savings will be increased by the return on your investment, plus a percentage of your ​monthly salary ​(annual salary / 12). Write a program to calculate how many months it will take you to save up enough money for a down payment. You will want your main variables to be floats, so you should cast user inputs to floats.
   Your program should ask the user to enter the following variables:

The starting annual salary (annual_salary)
The portion of salary to be saved (portion_saved)
The cost of your dream home (total_cost)

**Test Case 1**

Enter your annual salary:​ 120000 Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal:​ .10 Enter the cost of your dream home:​ 1000000 Number of months:​ 183

Comment: then only place you print `n` is in your `else` case and at that point nothing happened to it so it is `0` as initialized.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Is there something wrong with my for statement then? I assumed if current savings > down payment the n would print after being incremented

Comment: I edited my answer to take into account the other mistake as well. If you change both things, your code should work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `n =+ 1` but I think you mean `n += 1`

Also `int(.25)` evaluates to `0`, I think you want `int(total_cost*.25)`. As your code is, the `if` statement will always evaluate to `False` because `current_savings == 0` and `portion_down_payment == 0`

More generally, when your code isn't working as expected, you should put in either `print()` or `assert` statements to narrow down where your code is deviating from what you expect. For example, before the `if` statement you could have it print the two values you are comparing.